# Joomla 3.x: Limit a module's size

Tags: html, css, joomla, resize

I am new to Joomla and rather unexperienced with html/css. I have a module that adds a menu to my website. The menu is displayed correctly, but it seems that the position I use dedicates much more width to the position than I fill. 
How do I resize a position or the size of a module that takes the position? I can't see any settings  that would allow me to alter the width.

I assume I have to hack around in the css files then, right? How do I find the css responsible for the expansion in width of the module? I looked naively for 'position-8', but that would have been to easy.

I appreciate any pointer.

The screenshot shows my menu located in position-8 and the size of the position (the grey area). Next to it starts the article-content area. I want to fix this whole, but I am unsure of how to do that.
[image]

Firebug shows me this html-values for the grey-area

```
<div id="sidebar" class="span3" style="overflow: visible; z-index: 1;">
<div class="sidebar-nav" style="overflow: visible; z-index: 1;">
<div class="moduletable sidebar.swmenu" style="overflow: visible; z-index: 1;">
<h3>LTL Menu</h3>
<table id="outertable" class="outer" align="left" style="overflow: visible; z-index: 1;">
<tbody style="overflow: visible; z-index: 1;">
<tr style="overflow: visible; z-index: 1;">
<td style="overflow: visible; z-index: 1;">
<div id="outerwrap" style="overflow: visible; z-index: 1;">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<hr style="display:block;clear:left;margin:-0.66em 0;visibility:hidden;">
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
</div>
</div>
```

The index.php of my template, I want to change the size of the position-8

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Site
 * @subpackage  Templates.protostar
 *
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2014 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

// Getting params from template
$params = JFactory::getApplication()->getTemplate(true)->params;

$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$this->language = $doc->language;
$this->direction = $doc->direction;

// Detecting Active Variables
$option   = $app->input->getCmd('option', '');
$view     = $app->input->getCmd('view', '');
$layout   = $app->input->getCmd('layout', '');
$task     = $app->input->getCmd('task', '');
$itemid   = $app->input->getCmd('Itemid', '');
$sitename = $app->getCfg('sitename');

if($task == "edit" || $layout == "form" )
{
    $fullWidth = 1;
}
else
{
    $fullWidth = 0;
}

// Add JavaScript Frameworks
JHtml::_('bootstrap.framework');
$doc->addScript('templates/' .$this->template. '/js/template.js');

// Add Stylesheets
$doc->addStyleSheet('templates/'.$this->template.'/css/template.css');

// Load optional RTL Bootstrap CSS
JHtml::_('bootstrap.loadCss', false, $this->direction);

// Add current user information
$user = JFactory::getUser();

// Adjusting content width
if ($this->countModules('position-7') && $this->countModules('position-8'))
{
    $span = "span6";
}
elseif ($this->countModules('position-7') && !$this->countModules('position-8'))
{
    $span = "span9";
}
elseif (!$this->countModules('position-7') && $this->countModules('position-8'))
{
    $span = "span9";
}
else
{
    $span = "span12";
}

// Logo file or site title param
if ($this->params->get('logoFile'))
{
    $logo = '<img src="'. JUri::root() . $this->params->get('logoFile') .'" alt="'. $sitename .'" />';
}
elseif ($this->params->get('sitetitle'))
{
    $logo = '<span class="site-title" title="'. $sitename .'">'. htmlspecialchars($this->params->get('sitetitle')) .'</span>';
}
else
{
    $logo = '<span class="site-title" title="'. $sitename .'">'. $sitename .'</span>';
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" dir="<?php echo $this->direction; ?>">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <jdoc:include type="head" />
    <?php
    // Use of Google Font
    if ($this->params->get('googleFont'))
    {
    ?>
        <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=<?php echo $this->params->get('googleFontName');?>' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
        <style type="text/css">
            h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,.site-title{
                font-family: '<?php echo str_replace('+', ' ', $this->params->get('googleFontName'));?>', sans-serif;
            }
        </style>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    <?php
    // Template color
    if ($this->params->get('templateColor'))
    {
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        body.site
        {
            border-top: 3px solid <?php echo $this->params->get('templateColor');?>;
            background-color: <?php echo $this->params->get('templateBackgroundColor');?>
        }
        a
        {
            color: <?php echo $this->params->get('templateColor');?>;
        }
        .navbar-inner, .nav-list > .active > a, .nav-list > .active > a:hover, .dropdown-menu li > a:hover, .dropdown-menu .active > a, .dropdown-menu .active > a:hover, .nav-pills > .active > a, .nav-pills > .active > a:hover,
        .btn-primary
        {
            background: <?php echo $this->params->get('templateColor');?>;
        }
        .navbar-inner
        {
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), inset 0 30px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), inset 0 30px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
            box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), inset 0 30px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
        }
    </style>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/media/jui/js/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body class="site <?php echo $option
    . ' view-' . $view
    . ($layout ? ' layout-' . $layout : ' no-layout')
    . ($task ? ' task-' . $task : ' no-task')
    . ($itemid ? ' itemid-' . $itemid : '')
    . ($params->get('fluidContainer') ? ' fluid' : '');
?>">

    <!-- Body -->
    <div class="body">
        <div class="container<?php echo ($params->get('fluidContainer') ? '-fluid' : '');?>">
            <!-- Header -->
            <header class="header" role="banner">
                <div class="header-inner clearfix">
                    <a class="brand pull-left" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>">
                        <?php echo $logo;?> <?php if ($this->params->get('sitedescription')) { echo '<div class="site-description">'. htmlspecialchars($this->params->get('sitedescription')) .'</div>'; } ?>
                    </a>
                    <div class="header-search pull-right">
                        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-0" style="none" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
            <?php if ($this->countModules('position-1')) : ?>
            <nav class="navigation" role="navigation">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-1" style="none" />
            </nav>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="banner" style="xhtml" />
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <?php if ($this->countModules('position-8')) : ?>
                <!-- Begin Sidebar -->
                <div id="sidebar" class="span3">
                    <div class="sidebar-nav">
                        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-8" style="xhtml" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- End Sidebar -->
                <?php endif; ?>
                <main id="content" role="main" class="<?php echo $span;?>">
                    <!-- Begin Content -->
                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-3" style="xhtml" />
                    <jdoc:include type="message" />
                    <jdoc:include type="component" />
                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-2" style="none" />
                    <!-- End Content -->
                </main>
                <?php if ($this->countModules('position-7')) : ?>
                <div id="aside" class="span3">
                    <!-- Begin Right Sidebar -->
                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-7" style="well" />
                    <!-- End Right Sidebar -->
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer class="footer" role="contentinfo">
        <div class="container<?php echo ($params->get('fluidContainer') ? '-fluid' : '');?>">
            <hr />
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="footer" style="none" />
            <p class="pull-right">
                <a href="#top" id="back-top">
                    <?php echo JText::_('TPL_PROTOSTAR_BACKTOTOP'); ?>
                </a>
            </p>
            <p>
                &copy; <?php echo date('Y'); ?> <?php echo $sitename; ?>
            </p>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="debug" style="none" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes this is CSS. Use your console (F12) to debug this and see what you have to change. You may also wrap your position into a custom div with the CSS you want. Give at least the code of the template

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure which information you want me to post? I use the preinstalled protostar template. Shall I post the templateDetail.xml?

Comment: yes, just the positions part and also the `template.php` (the part where the position is)

Comment: I added the index.php that is the one you meant with template.php, right?

Comment: Without access to your actual site is hard to give you exact instructions but you should use Firebug or any other developer tools to get the class of the menu wrapper div (the one with the white background) and set its width to 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check:

```
<?php if ($this->countModules('position-8')) : ?>
                <!-- Begin Sidebar -->
                <div id="sidebar" class="span3">
                    <div class="sidebar-nav">
                        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-8" style="xhtml" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- End Sidebar -->
                <?php endif; ?>
```

`position-8` is inside `div #sidebar`

You have to add a suffix to your module settings:
Advanced -> Module Class Suffix: mymenu

Then in your template css under: templates/your_template/css/template.css

You have to add: `div#sidebar div.mymenu{ width: 100%; }`

*change 100% with the number that will fit better

**EDIT:**

Your template is responsive based on bootstrap. You have to edit `<div id="sidebar" class="span3">` span3 value to span2 or span1 and in your head section:

```
// Adjusting content width
if ($this->countModules('position-7') && $this->countModules('position-8'))
{
    $span = "span6";
}
elseif ($this->countModules('position-7') && !$this->countModules('position-8'))
{
    $span = "span9";
}
elseif (!$this->countModules('position-7') && $this->countModules('position-8'))
{
    $span = "span9";
}
else
{
    $span = "span12";
}
```

increase the span9 to span10 or span11 to fill the gap.

Comment: I added the line to the template, but unfortunately it had no effect. I intentionally set the value really low to see if it has any effect, it had not :/.

Comment: In order to help you please post a screenshot of the site and how you want to look.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the respective position and the space it takes.

Comment: Please check my edited answer. Your template is based on bootstrap so in order to change the width you have to edit the appropriate span classes. The span sum in each line always has to be 12.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much!

I only had to replace span3 with span2, now the distance to the article area is fine.

Comment: Nice to hear that! Please check header part also that needs to increase span9 to span10.

Comment: That causes no visible change. What exactly are those spans good for?

Comment: It checks if template has active modules in position 7 and / or position 8 and put the appropriate span to the content area. Once you have changed the span3 to span2 to the sidebar, you have to increase by one (span9 to span10) the content area span in order the sum of spans be always 12.